# How to auto linewrap comments in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, comments, word-wrap, xml-comments

I'd like to have a single command to auto-linewrap the XML-style comments in .NET.

Example:

```
/// <summary>
/// This comment line should be
/// on one line, and other lines in this <summary> block should be wordwrapped.
/// </summary>
```

I wouldn't mind buying some of the commercial Visual Studio plugins, if they are capable of doing this.

Comment: when you click three times symbol '/' vs creates summary (is it resharper feature?)

Comment: Pressing "/" 3 times creates the summary block as default in Visual Studio; it's not part of Resharper; though you can get plug-ins that intelligently populate the summary instead.

Comment: Which plugins intelligently populate the summary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've written an addin for Visual Studio, [AtomineerUtils Pro Documentation](http://www.atomineerutils.com/) which will update and word-wrap both normal comments and documentation comments (in XML, Doxygen, Qt and JavaDoc formats). (It's not free, but it's very inexpensive and there's a 30 day free trial)

It tries to intelligently preserve important newlines - text such as indentation, bullet lists, blank lines or a double space at the end of a line (among other things) will all be used as hints to the wrapping engine to ensure that your formatting is not lost.

Answer (score 6):

Try the trial of [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), it states it formats XML Doc Comments (Go [Here](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp50/Code_Cleanup__Creating_Custom_Profiles.html) and search for  XML doc comments for more information) and tends to be very customisable.

If that doesn't work, the closest thing I could find was on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/commentreflower.aspx) , it's intended for Visual Studio 2003; however is open source so you may be able to get it working without the expensive of a third party plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Add a <para /> in your comments